# Automatically creating a folder on share and assigning correct permissions

Tags: windows, powershell, dictionary, permissions

I have this software that requires every user to have a personal folder only they can look into on a share, just like a home folder. Now I'm working on this script that is being executed every time a user logs in, I want the script to check if there already is a folder with their SAMaccountname on the share, and if there's not, it has to create one with correct permissions.

I'm not good with PowerShell at all and can't come any further at all, I have the part where it checks it and assigns correct permissions for the user. But also the domain admins need full control, and the service account needs R&W permissions. Is there anyone who can help me further with finishing the script? Any effort and help is gladly appreciated.

Current script: the path is weird due to the fact I was testing it on VMWare.

```
$Path = "\\Win-hnf1r0tnhgh\F\Scans\$($ENV:USERNAME)"

if (!(Test-Path -Path $Path)) {

    New-Item -Path $Path -ItemType Directory

    }

    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Path -ErrorAction 'Stop'
    $Acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $True) > $null
    Set-Acl -Path $Path -AclObject $Acl -ErrorAction 'Stop'
    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Path
    $Acl.Access.Where{$_.IdentityReference -eq "BUILTIN\Users"}.ForEach{$Acl.RemoveAccessRule($_) > $null}
    $PermissionChange = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule]::new($ENV:USERNAME, 'Modify', "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
    $Acl.AddAccessRule($PermissionChange) > $null
    Set-Acl -Path $Path -AclObject $Acl -ErrorAction 'Stop'
```

Answer (score 0):

I find ACL modification using native powershell or even .NET to be overly complicated.

You can use this to set full control with a single line:

```
ICACLS "$($Path)" /grant "DOMAINSHORTNAME\$($ENV:USERNAME):(OI)(CI)F" /T
```

You can adjust the ICACLS cmd anyway you need, tons of examples online

Simply run the command a few times, one time for each account that needs rights.